# Sorting Twice with an SQL Query

Tags: sql, postgresql

So, say I have a table of entries which have a product name, a user, and the product's pricing.

My problem is that I want to obtain a result set that groups the products bought a single user together, and then sorts those products lexicographically.

So, something like where every product bought a user whose name starts with an A is grouped in their own little block, with each product also appearing in alphabetical order (Candy before Cat food, for example), with a user whose name starts with P afterward.

Can someone explain how I might begin to do this?

Comment: "order by userName, productName"

Comment: `ORDER BY user, product_name` to start with. Is it what you're asking about?

Answer (score 2):

An SQL query returns a table of rows and columns. You can have one column for the client and another for the product and sort by client and inside by product (`ORDER BY client, product`). You don't get different "blocks" of data.

If you want this more beautiful, you need some software to create a report (i.e. data with a layout) based on the query.

What you can do with SQL, though, is suppress data, such as:

```
select 
  case when client = lag(client) over (order by client, product) then null else client end 
    as client,
  product
from bought
order by client, product;
```

Sample result:

```
client  |  product
--------+--------
Max     |  cup
        |  saucer
        |  plate
Elsa    |  mug
        |  plate
```